# Lambda does not have permission to access the ECR image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-sam-cli

With the recent release of Docker Images for `Lambda` functions, I've decided to try out this functionality using `CloudFormation`.

So, the lambda below considers a docker image stored in `Elastic Container Registry`, with permissions to access the image following the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html).

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: lambda-docker-image

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 180

Resources:
  DockerAsImage:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      FunctionName: DockerAsImage
      ImageUri: ??????????????.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/????:latest
      PackageType: Image
      Policies: 
        - Version: '2012-10-17' 
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 
                - ecr:*
                - ecr-public:*
                - sts:GetServiceBearerToken
              Resource: "*"
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
```

I'm using `sam` to deploy the template in `us-west-2` with

```
sam deploy -t template.yaml --capabilities "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM" --region "us-west-2" --stack-name "lambda-docker-example" --s3-bucket "my-bucket" --s3-prefix "sam_templates/lambda-docker-example" --force-upload  --no-confirm-changeset
```

However, just after the `IAM` Role is succesfuly created, the `Lambda` function fails to create with the following error

```
Lambda does not have permission to access the ECR image. Check the ECR permissions. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;
```

even though the role has access to any `ecs` resource. Another way I've tried is to create a separate role and assigned it to lambda through `Role: !GetAtt Role.Arn`, this approach doesn't work too.

Comment: Do your IAM user/role has permissions to ECR? For using Image-based lambda function, you as a user/role which creates the function needs ECR permissions as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html#configuration-images-permissions). Can you check that?

Comment: @Marcin I had the same issue and your advice solved it!

Comment: @alexyz78 Thanks for letting me know. If it will for the OP I can will provide more info in the answer.

Comment: @Marcin yes indeed those two permissions solve the issue, additionally to push a docker image to ecr it was necessary `ecr: InitiateLayerUpload` . Thank you very much Marcin, AWS docs doesn't tend to be an easy guideline. Feel free to share your answer.

Comment: @MiguelTrejo Thanks, answer added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To use image-based lambdas, it is the IAM user/role that requires ECR permissions, not the function itself. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html#configuration-images-permissions):

> Make sure that the permissions for the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) **user or role that creates the function** contain the AWS managed policies **GetRepositoryPolicy** and **SetRepositoryPolicy**.

In addition to the two permissions listed above, the `ecr: InitiateLayerUpload` is also needed.

Comment: Hmm, we seemed to also need `LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy`.

Comment: Should be ECR resource policy or IAM role policy? I have added to IAM role policy and it does not work

Answer (score 10):

For a lambda in account 222222222222 to use an ECR image in 11111111111 then you need to follow https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-amazon-ecr-access-for-aws-lambda/

The most important IAM part is to set the following Repository policy on the 11111111111 repo:

```
      RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: CrossAccountPermission
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ecr:BatchGetImage
              - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root
          - Sid: LambdaECRImageCrossAccountRetrievalPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ecr:BatchGetImage
              - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Condition:
              StringLike:
                aws:sourceArn:
                  - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:222222222222:function:*
```

Answer (score 5):

You must to add the following policy to your User and the Role that will be asociated to the AWS Lambda. This policy enables ECR actions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issues with all the required AWS lambda policies in place. What helped me was adding permissions in ECR

```json
{
      "Sid": "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ]
}
```

Although aws also says if lambda has policies (`ecr:getRepositoryPolicy` and `ecr:setRepositoryPolicy`) then we don't need to add permission in ECR lambda automatically does that.

> If the Amazon ECR repository does not include these permissions, Lambda adds `ecr:BatchGetImage` and `ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer` to the container image repository permissions. Lambda can add these permissions only if the Principal calling Lambda has `ecr:getRepositoryPolicy` and `ecr:setRepositoryPolicy` permissions.

[Reference #1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=341108), [#2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html)

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue, when I had ECR in `Account A` and needed to create a Lambda in `Account B`.

The solution was adding the following to ECR repo in account A :

[Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-amazon-ecr-access-for-aws-lambda/)

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [  
    {
      "Sid": "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicyCrossAccount",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:{account_id}:function:*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "CrossAccountPermission",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My conribution does not really answer the OP's problem but it might help someone looking for a solution to their problem - if it is the same case as mine.

I found out through some trail and error (not with ANY help from CloudTrail or any  docs from AWS) that the problem was not with Lambda's permissions to GET the images from ECR, but to be able to set ECR's policy (ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy) because of an SCP explicit deny.

If you want to see if this is your case, try to access the repo and change the policy, if you can't, this is it. There is no use in trying anything else.