# Change lambda from supported runtime to docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda which was created and deployed with CloudFormation. The lambda, as of now, uses the supported .NET Core 3.1 runtime but I want to use the "unsupported" .Net Core 5 so I have created a Docker image [which the lambda can run](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-container-image-support-for-aws-lambda-with-aws-sam/).

The problem I have is that CloudFormation can't seem to change the lambda from running a supported runtime to running a Docker image. I get `Please don't provide ImageUri when updating a function with packageType Zip.` when updating the CloudFormation stack with the updated template.

This is how my CloudFormation template looks like:

```yaml
MyFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
        PackageType: Image
        ImageUri: <uri-to-ecr-docker-image>
        ...
    Metadata:
        Dockerfile: Dockerfile
        DockerContext: .
        DockerTag: v1
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Configuring functions defined as container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html)

> You cannot convert an existing .zip file archive function to use a container image. You must create a new function.

Comment: Thank you, completely missed that. I renamed the function in my template and then I had to add these permissions https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151634/6193522

Comment: +1. Just to clarify what to do : you need to create new lambda function (your current is not for image-based deployments) with "Image" option, after this - should works/deploy as expected

Answer (score 0):

simple way
Deploy a fresh environment with a docker runtime from the start.